# How to convert a Microsoft SQL date to a vba string?

Tags: sql-server, string, excel, vba, date

I have a database in Microsoft SQL with 3 columns. The last column is a date which has the format: dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm-ss (ex: 20-May-15 22:31:38).
I managed to export the other 2 columns in Excel, but when I try to import the last column it gives me the next error: "Run-time error '3265': Application-defined or object-defined error".

My vba script is:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim con As ADODB.Connection
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim r As Integer
    Set con = New ADODB.Connection
    Dim s As String 
    con.ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=AEG-PC\WINCC; Initial Catalog=DBRapPlopeni; User ID=AEGRap; Password=1qaz2wsx; Trusted_Connection=yes"
    con.Open
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
    rs.ActiveConnection = con
    rs.Open "EXEC SotoredProcedure 20,05,2015"
    r = 5
    Do While Not rs.EOF
      Cells(r, 2) = rs.Fields(0)
      Cells(r, 3) = rs.Fields(1)
      Cells(r, 4) = rs.Fields(2) ' this field of date which cannot be imported
rs.MoveNext
r = r + 1
Loop
End Sub
```

I tried to convert date field in a string format but it didn't work for me.
Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: try to convert to string using CStr? Are any values null?

Comment: also please remove real usernames and passwords from the question if indeed they are real...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had a similar issue and I used the GetRows method to store the data in an array and manipulate them from there.

Something like the below:

Replace:

```
Do While Not rs.EOF
  Cells(r, 2) = rs.Fields(0)
  Cells(r, 3) = rs.Fields(1)
  Cells(r, 4) = rs.Fields(2) ' this field of date which cannot be imported
  rs.MoveNext
  r = r + 1
Loop
```

with

```
dim ar() as variant
ar = rs.GetRows
```

and then do a for loop to store the array data in the required cells.

```
for r =0 to ubound(ar,2) 'your array has 0 to ubound(ar,2) rows
        cells(r,2) = ar(1,r)
        cells(r,3) = ar(2,r)
        cells(r,4) = ar(3,r)
next r
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Ok. But what should I put in for loop? I mean how does it know where to put datas in Excel? I tried:

Dim ar() As Variant
ar = rs.GetRows

For col = 2 To 4
Cells(r, col) = ar()
' Cells(r + 1, col) = ar()
Next col

Comment: i edited my answer to include the array for loop. does this work?

Comment: Thanks! I'll try tomorrow your solution and I'll let you know if it works.

Comment: It works but I have now another problem. My table from SQL has 19 rows. When I apply your method it returns in Excel from 6th to 19th row. The first rows are omitted. Why? Thanks!

Comment: what is the first value that you give to r? 0 or 5? Because in your first code r starts from 5 so I am guessing you have done the same.

Comment: I want to insert all my 19 rows from SQL starting from 5th row in Excel

Comment: ok so change the following on the last for loop in the answer:
        cells(r+5, 2) = ar(1,r)
        cells(r+5, 3) = ar(2,r)
        cells(r+5, 4) = ar(3,r)

Comment: Now my rows are with 5 rows below, but from 5th to 9th row from Excel no information is showed.

Comment: Done! I solved it. I put in for loop r=0. Many, many thanks for your big help!